# image how does setting src fire onload

Tags: javascript

I am curious about how the image onload and src work.  We first setup onload which gets used when src is set to a value.  How is this done?  More importantly, how can I setup my code (non-image related) to run a function when an property is set?  I have looked at a list of events and there isn't, to my eyes, an appropriate event for this.  Thanks.